# I have an issue with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

recently, I have downloaded videos from youtube on learning bootstrap 4 for responsive web design and everything works fine for me when I use 
`<div class="col-md-6>` the md class for the medium screen and lg class for large screen works fine but xl class for the extra small devices and sm class for small devices no matter how I zoom the page and I have downloaded responsive website test extension for chrome but still nothing. this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learn BOOTSTRAP CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
# this is the parent class and it should take the entire page width
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 bg-primary">
    <p>this is the primary color</p>
    <div class="row">
      # and this is the child class and it should take 6 col of it parent class
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 bg-success">
    <p>this is the success color</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: am a newbie in bootstrap and i searched in google for an answer for this but i didn't find any

Comment: edit the question and clarify what's not working. *"the md and lg works fine for me but xl and sm no matter how I scale the page"* doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your code doesn't show a breakpoint for the smallest device size (`col-*`).  Also where is the rest of your Bootstrap includes?  What do you mean "zoom the page" ?

Comment: am working on my desktop and I zoom the page to fit the mobile screen

Comment: @Mr.Awad don't use the page zoom to test mobile... that won't work. Instead if you are using Chrome use [chrome dev tools devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/)

Comment: you also need to add all of the Bootstrap js at the bottom of your page http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

look like I didn't work because I was using Bootstrap 4, when I used bootstrap
3 the code works fine for me